# Programmatically change contents of input with type="file"

Tags: javascript, fileapi, filelist

I have a input element with type="file". I am using two different APIs. The first allows me to view a preview of the file in an img tag (only images will be uploaded). The second allows me to rotate the img and retrieve a dataUrl of the new image's contents.

When I submit the form containing my input element, the server receives the file that was originally uploaded by the user, not the file that was rotated by the 2nd API. This makes sense. I need a way to change the file that my input element points to.

My understanding is that an input element points to a FileList object. Since the input element does not allow for multiple uploads, that FileList object has a length of 1. The FileList object can be used to access that single File object, which just contains metadata about the uploaded file. I can actually read the contents of the uploaded file using the FileReader API, but that's the issue... I can only read the contents. How can I replace them? Or is the solution to create a new FileList object that points to a new File object and then somehow point the input element to the new FileList?

Thank you,
Nick

Comment: Actually [`FileList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList) is a property of `input type="file"`. It is read-only. The `value` of the input can be read on server-side only. If you want to rotate the image on client-side, send the original file and rotating parameters to server, and re-rotate the image on server.

Comment: That was my last resort... There's seriously no other way to do this? That seems ridiculous to me. I cannot replace the FileList property?

Comment: Can you think of the terrible security implications that would result if JS was allowed to replace the contents of an input type="file" field without the users input?

Comment: Like I said, it's read-only. `value` can't be accessed with JS at all. Or actually you can read it, but it contains a "fake path" + filename only.

Comment: Good point Adam. That makes far more sense. Alright. Thank you for the advice guys

Comment: Of course you can read the contents (bytes) of the file that the user selected! https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications